# ExportToHttpResponse Failing {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack}

Tags: c#, exception, crystal-reports

First of all I am New to C# Programming, I am facing the **Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack** Message in my project  when I Generate the crystal Report in PDF Format  I had searched for Answers in Google and also seen many links including [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/817776da-13da-43f5-a189-1727ce4f3b6b/) but nothing helped me could anyone tell me what would be the Mistake

The Code I tried is,

```
  protected void getpkeybt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool ch = checkFromToDate();
    int i=checkTxt();
    if ( ch == true && i==1)
    {
        try
        {
            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(frmtxtdt.Text);
            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(frmtxtdt.Text);
            string frtxt = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", dt);
            string totxt = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", dt1);
            DataSet ds = Namespace.SP.EStoredprocedure(frtxt,totxt).GetDataSet();
            if (!IsPageRefresh)
           {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0
                && frtxt == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString()
                && totxt == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString())
            {
                ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Passkeys";

                ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/XML/Passkeys.xml"));
                string filename = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Pkey_rpt.rpt");
                rpt.Load(filename);
                rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
                rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Passkeys");

            }
            else if(frmtxtdt.Text.Trim() !=null && totxtdt.Text.Trim()!=null)
            {
                if (frtxt   == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString()
                     && totxt == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString() 
                     && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {

                    lblmsg.Text = "Pass Key(s) Not Yet Delivered for the Selected Date...";

                }
                else
                {

                    lblmsg.Text = "There is No Schedule for the Selected date....";
                }

            }
         }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That message usually isn't an exception, but rather a *mea culpa* from the debugger, explaining why it can't show you relevant debug info for watches/locals/etc. Can you show us which line appears to be throwing the exception, as well as what the actual exception is?

Comment: What is **mea culpa** Could you Please Explain it  If the Condition is Correct the code is Excecuting after ` rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Passkeys");
` I am getting this error caught at Catch block.

Comment: What I mean is that usually that message is the debugger telling you that it's not able to collect good information, because there is native/optimized frame on the top of the stack (and so it can't execute the managed code it would need to give you the relevant information.)

Comment: Also, what kind of project is that? WinForms? WPF? ASP.Net?

Comment: @ Delv Thanks My project is a WPF Project

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `ExportToHttpResponse()` is calling `Response.End()`, which ends the response the quickest way it knows how: *by aborting the thread*. That bubbles a `ThreadAbortException`, which your `try/catch` is handling. However, the problem with thread abort exceptions is that they are by default automatically re-thrown at the end of a `catch` block. That's a problem for you, since you don't actually want this thread killed (I'm guessing it's your UI thread.) As such, you need to call `Thread.ResetAbort()` in your `catch` block, which instructs the run-time to stop re-throwing the exception.

Note that this is generally *not* recommended (neither aborting threads from the sky, or else stopping an abort when it does occur.) However, this is a known "feature" of both `Response.End()` and general, in `ExportToHttpResponse()` in particular, so in your case I think it's justified.

Comment: @ Delv the Same Error is Thrown in some other Page which is Used to get reports in PDF format but the PDF will be generated, but only in My Page the Error is Thrown but the PDF is Not Generated What may be the Problem

Comment: @ Delv When I Put `Thread.ResetAbort()` in the Catch Block it Throws the Exception **Thread is Being Aborted**